# Turn PyCharm package back to a directory in Project Tool Window

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I don't know how it happened, but a normal PyCharm directory turned into a package that doesn't contain `__init__.py`

[image]

I have tried to import functions from that directory before, could this have caused the problem? (Now I don't import anything from that directory, but it is still a package with a dot) How can I turn it back to a standard directory again?  I have tried to add a `init.py` file and delete it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the folder -> Mark directory as -> Unmark as Namespace Package.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It worked. I'm nowwondering what caused the problem

Comment: You might have accidentally set it with the mouse or a keyboard shortcut.